# Why do strptime and strftime behave differently, and what do you do about it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm on Python 2.5 and running in App Engine, doing pagination with code that looks like:

```
NEXT_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

current = model.completed_on.strftime(NEXT_FORMAT)

completed_before = datetime.datetime.strptime(current, NEXT_FORMAT)
```

Every now and then strftime will drop out a time that looks like `2011-11-24 05:13:54.355436` and then strptime will blow up trying to eat it with

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .355436
```

So, why if you are using a format that says %S is seconds as a decimal number is it creating a floating point number?  And it that is going to happen, why doesn't strptime deal with it in the same way?

Comment: Can you log the value of completed_on before you call strftime?  Seems strange that strftime would just tack on microseconds when you didn't ask for it.

Comment: My solution so far was to do current.split('.')[0] which gets the job done.  I think this is the first toe stubber I have hit in Python, everything else has worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Change it to this:

```
NEXT_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
```

This will convert the microsecond part as well.

Or, if you want to strip off the microseconds, you can use replace before you call strptime.

```
current = current.replace(microsecond=0)
```

Comment: I believe `%f` was added in 2.6 and the OP appears to be using 2.5.

Comment: Good catch.  In that case I think using replace will have to be called before any call to strptime.  I wonder where the microseconds are coming from.

Comment: the strftime is surely going to be being done by the native c implementation, would be interesting to know what platform this is being observed on ...

Comment: Google App Engine (see the tags)